# In Nginx how to allow some IPs & allow all requests from mobile devices?

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

I want to

1) Deny all IP address except `10.1.1.1` (from browser)

2) Allow all requests from android(or any other) devices

I have following nginx code snippet, but it gives error

> "allow" directive is not allowed here

```
location / {

            allow 10.1.1.1; //allow for this IP only and deny for all browser request
            deny  all; 
            if ($http_user_agent ~* "(android") { //allow for android user-agent for now
                 allow all; // allow access to all mobile users
            }
.
.
.}
```

How to achieve this or any alternative to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to block the end user, IF the client's IP is not 10.1.1.1
AND IF the user-agent is NOT Android

For all other conditions, you want to serve the correct content. So, place the following in the vhost configuration file:

```
        if ($remote_addr != 10.1.1.1 ) {
                set $myvar "N";

        }
        if ($http_user_agent !~* "android") {
               set $myvar "${myvar}A";
        }

        if ($myvar = NA) {
                return 403;
           }
```

Here I have used a variable $myvar.

Value N is assigned if the IP is NOT 10.1.1.1.
Value A is assigned if the User-Agent is NOT android.
Value NA is assigned only If the client's IP is not 10.1.1.1. AND the user-agent is not Android. In this case a 403 is returned to block the user.